# Where to locate DNS server addresses on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns

I had manually entered DNS server addresses in TCP/IP settings (Local Area Connection), but i accidentally removed them and i don't know where i got it from. The only thing i have is a system image backup, so i could restore it and read the DNS addresses, but that would be too cumbersome and i don't have a spare drive.
However i can open the VHD system image and browse all the folders.
Is there a physical location on the drive of where all the DNS entries are stored in a file or something?
Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it really that tough, it's just DNS? Ask your ISP or check their website, or just use Google (8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4), OpenDNS (208.67.222.222/208.67.220.220), Quad9 DNS (9.9.9.9), or any from this webpage https://usefulpcguide.com/16978/best-public-dns-servers-you-must-know/ Most are probably better/faster than your ISP anyway.

Comment: Haha yes i know, but they were really fast and secure DNS servers and i  certainly wouldn't want to use from Google or OpenDNS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not actually tried this - however it seems correct
What you want is in the registry (on my system)  its at HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{GUID}\NameServer

So you need to grab the file which contains HKLM\System - which I believe is

> C:\Windows\System32\config\system.

(no extension) and open it with regedit. Select the LOCAL_USERS  and use Load Hive  in RegEdit and navigate to the Key undert the hive you load.

Comment: That's the best answer you're gonna get because it's 1000000% correct.

Comment: Thank you! Same solution, wish i refreshed the page sooner before typing an answer!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution,

- Open the system image backup VHD file with 7-zip
- Browse to Windows\System32\config (where the actual registry files are located) 
  and copy the "SYSTEM" file
- Open the Registry Editor and click on "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
- Go to the File menu and click on "Load Hive"
- Select the "SYSTEM" file that you copied and open it, give it a name
- Now, in the loaded hive, navigate to 
  "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces"
  click on the various keys and look at "NameServer" until you find all the DNS
  entries
- After copying the DNS addresses, make sure to unload the hive afterwards